# woo commerce products not displaying in admin

Tags: woocommerce

After upgrading to woo-commerce 2.2.8 , I've run into this weird issue..

everything is intact.. including the frontend shop and products .. but products are not showing in the admin page!!

after hours of scratching my head I happened to check in the console and there seems to be a javascript error that's causing the products from not showing up!! it looks like this:

> 'wp' is not defined
>
> File: meta-boxes-product-variation.min.js, Line: 122, Column: 18

I really don't know what to do... do I need to replace this file ?

Comment: Are there any other JS files that are failing to load?

Comment: No.. I checked it.. all the js files are loaded. the same edit page for wordpress pages shows all the pages and posts.. but not for products!

Comment: Have you tried disabling all other plugins?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multi vendor plugin and made yourself a vendor as well as administrator you won't see products in the admin panel. Remove yourself as vendor and that will solve the issue,